# How much routine-fragmented should be the code?

Tags: c++, arduino, generic-programming

I am developing a thermostat firmware that handles different states, an OLED, and reacts to some push buttons, among other tasks.

I managed to bind the OLED views, the heater state and the button in a way that I am quite satisfied with, using callbacks depending on which state I am. Example:

```
static PushButtonState pb_state = PB_LONG_CLICK_CONFIRMED;
...
state_current->click_callback(pb_state);
state_current->oled_update();
```

`state_current` is:

```
typedef struct {
  VoidCallback thermo_logic;
  VoidCallback oled_update;
  ClickCallback click_callback;
} StateFunctions;

StateFunctions state_time_to_off {
  ThermoLogicTimeToOff,
  OledUpdateTimeToOff,
  ClickTimeToOff
};

StateFunctions *state_current = &state_time_to_off;
```

Using this method I avoid switch-casing all around the code, to know the current state.

At the end, I have the following code for `ClickTimeToOff`:

```
void ClickTimeToOff(PushButtonState click_type) {
  if (click_type == PB_SHORT_CLICK_CONFIRMED) {
    td.remaining_time_s += TIME_INCREMENT1_S;
    if (td.remaining_time_s > TIME_TO_OFF_MAX_S) {
      td.remaining_time_s = TIMER_DISABLED;
    }
  } else if (click_type == PB_LONG_CLICK_CONFIRMED) {
    oled.clear();
    SetThermoState(&state_time_to_on);
  } else if (click_type == PB_VERYLONG_CLICK_CONFIRMED) {
    /* TBD */
  } else {
    /* Nothing */
  }
}
```

Which could be easily split to 3 separate functions, and instead of having `click_callback`, to have `short_click_callback`, `long_click_callback` and `verylong_click_callback`.

I am doing this to follow the [Write Short Functions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Write_Short_Functions) guide, but I am starting to feel that my code is too much fragmented. There are almost 30 functions in a relatively small project.

Is there any rule of thumb regarding how small functions should be? Anything I should avoid if using this callback mechanism?

Sorry if this question is too broad, but I've been wandering about this and I though I could find some answers here.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on [Code Review StackExchange?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Writing "short" functions is supposed to help you write functions which do one thing well and reliable. Usually people need to be pushed towards shorter functions to achieve that. If you personally feel that it is going too far, then you are probably right. After all you are the leading expert on your code. So I offer this view: "Is any pair of my functions strenuosly split just to make them short? Is there any one function, which does not do anything meaningful (not even through meaningfully using other clear functions) just because I made it short?"

Comment: Please read the [Guide to CR for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788), and consider posting as much of your code as possible on CR (with proper walkthrough/explanation/context) - don't worry about making a long post, max post capacity on CR is double that of SO exactly for this.